# ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7.

I am unable to configure handler 'file' dues to permissions.

Traceback is as follows:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/welnity/debug.log'
```

Comment: Looks like the application does not have access to the folder/log file. try chmod 777 to the folder and try again.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like the application does not have access to the folder/log file. try

```
chmod 777
```

to the folder and try again.

**Note**: *Please do not set 777 in PROD env*.

Comment: so what can I do in production then??

Comment: This answer collapses on itself. What you're proposing you're also (rightfully) encouraging NOT to do. This isn't a solution. It reveals that its a permission error, sure, but the error already makes that very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following files following this sub-directory(:/var/www/logs/projectname) in the root drive where your project is located Example, if the project's name is towns and is located in drive D, go to drive D and create a new folder var and in that www in that logs then the project name. In my case, D:/var/www/logs/towns Also, make sure this path is available

Answer (score 0):

Traceback says, that it's no "log" directory.

1. Create directory with name log in path

   ```
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/
   ```
2. Create empty file `.gitkeep`
3. After creating `.gitkeep` file, push it to GitHub

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the server please add `sudo` before the python. Meaning run:

```
sudo python manage.py your_commade
```

your_commade can be `runserver`